# laravel virtual field/column in query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a problem, I have 2 tables (posts, comments) and I want to select all posts + the number of their comments.
I could create a column "comments" in posts and write the counter in there, but I think that's a bad solution, so I am looking for something like virtual fields/columns in mysql to get the number of comments in the posts query.
Can I do this in Laravel?

Comment: Yeah you can do this in Laravel and it's quite easy.  Have you setup your relationships at all between the two tables?

Comment: Yes I have setup the foreign key in my Schema and a hasMany and belongsTo function in my models.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Comment` Model:

```
public function post(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Post', 'post_id');
}
```

In your `Post` Model:

```
public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('Comment', 'post_id');
}
```

In your controller, get a post with all its comments.

`$post = Post::with('comments')->find(1);`

In your view, display the post and the number of comments it has. Assuming your post has a `title` field.

```
Post Title: {{ $post->title }}
The post has {{ $post->comments->count() }} comments
```

Comment: Thanks but what I've forgot is, that I need all Posts in an array and parse it to json, because I will get them with angularjs, so the array is not the problem, but can I add a field "comments" in this array with the number of comments?